# dynamically fill spinner based on selection in another spinner

Tags: android, mono, spinner, fill

Im filling two spinners with text arrays from an xml resource file. depending on the selection in one spinner i want to fill the other with one of two different arrays from the xml resource file. im having trouble doing this in mono for android and cant find any examples online. please help

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                int pos, long id) {
    if(pos==0){
       Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
       ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.arrayone, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    else{
       Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
       ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.arraytwo, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

       }

    }
```

Comment: Can you help me with syntax when calling this event.

Answer (score 0):

your suggestion was a big help. With some changes, here is what worked for me in mono for android:

I have a spinner name spin3. You can select opt1 or opt2. There is a string array in the resources named opt1 and another named opt2. Then a second spinner (spinner4) changes its content to opt1 or opt2 based on what is selected in spin3.

```
public void spin3_onItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
Spinner spin = (Spinner)sender;
string pos = spin.SelectedItem.ToString();
if(pos=="opt1")
{
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)FindViewById(Resource.Id.spinner4); 
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource this, Resource.Array.opt1, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem); 
adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem); 
spinner.Adapter = adapter; 
} 
else
{ 
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) FindViewById(Resource.Id.spinner4); 
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(this, Resource.Array.opt2, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem); 
adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem); 
spinner.Adapter = adapter; 
}
}
```

Then to call the event use this

```
spin3.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(spin3_onItemSelected);
```